# Laravel 5 Auto logout — Session

Tags: ajax, session, laravel-5

I had a lot of research about it, but doesn't get a right answer. Also the person who asked it didn't have a response either. I know that it is not the right way to put on every page the check to check if `Auth::check()` and it looks messy on every page. Like on almost banking website, if you don't have an activity after a minute then you are going to logout automatically **without refreshing the page**, I think it is an `ajax` request. Do you have any suggestion about it? a **proper or best practice** to do it? `Im using laravel5.1`

Need your help guys. It also help other developers, and so, they may implement your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the session driver to handle your authentication, you can change the time period for an idle session to expire in the `/app/config/session.php file.`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: This is just the default values sir.

Comment: Here is the default values in my project 
    'lifetime' => time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, // One year

    'expire_on_close' => true,

Comment: Ow, what version of laravel you're using sir?  Im using Laravel5.1

Comment: I think you can change yours 

'lifetime' => time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
'expire_on_close' => true,

Comment: @LaravelMan does it fix ? if yes please check it

Comment: No sir, because it is obviously setting the time of session when logged in and setting whether it **expires** when you close the browser or not. You may read my question again sir. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 2:**

1. Go to your `.env` file and change `SESSION_DRIVER=file to SESSION_DRIVER=database.`
2. Next you will need to create a session migration: `php artisan session:table`
3. Now `composer dump-autoload` for good practice.
4. Finally migrate (`php artisan migrate`).

**NOTE:** I'm not 100% sure though if this is the case, but for me this solution worked. I am also aware that this question is really old, but both the developers I work with and myself have had this issue and there doesn't seem to be a solution, so Just though I'd post this.